# How should I initialize an array inside RecyclerView Adapter which has the size of a list while the list will not available on Adapter construction?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that will contain list of item retrieved from the internet. So at first, the list will be empty. After the data retrieved from the internet, it will update the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I can adapt the data into the `RecyclerView` just fine. But, I have an `ImageButton` for each of item which has different Image if it's clicked. If I initialize the flags array inside `onBindViewHolder`, each time I scrolled the `RecyclerView`, the flag array will be reinitialize to `false`. If I initialize it in the `Adapter` constructor, it will be 0 index since the list will be empty at first. Where should I put array initializing in adapter if the data will come at some amount of time later?

Below is my code, but the flag array (`isTrue`) is always reinitialize each time I scrolled my `RecyclerView`.

```js
public class SomethingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomethingAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> someList;
    private boolean[] isTrue;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView someText;
 public ImageButton someButton;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            someText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
     someButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        }
    }

    public SomethingAdapter(ArrayList<String> someList) {
        this.someList = someList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        //TODO: This thing will make isTrue always reinitialize if scrolled
        this.isTrue = new boolean[someList.getResults().size()];

        viewHolder.someText.setText(someList.get(position));

        if (isTrue[position]) {
            viewHolder.someButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_true);
        } else {
            viewHolder.someButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_false);
        }

        viewHolder.someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isTrue[position]) {
                    //Connect to the internet and if response is positive {
                        //isTrue[position] = false;
                        //viewHolder.someButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_false);
                    //}
                } else {
                    //Connect to the internet and if response is positive {
                        //isTrue[position] = true;
                        //viewHolder.someButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_true);
                    //}
                }
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return someList.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize it when you add items to `someList`.

Also, don't add click listener in your onBind, create it in `onCreateViewHolder`. You **cannot** use position in the click callback, instead you should be using ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition.

See docs for details:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH, int)

Comment: A example would have been nice.